# Google Map using Ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

> **What went wrong:
>           Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>        Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.**

I was trying to use ionic native google maps for an application using ionic 3. I did follow the steps mentioned in ionicframework site and when i took product build it shows lot of error with the following comments along with it. Also when i run 'ionic serve' the area where is to be displayed is blank.
I didnt get what is this error. I searched and went through many opinions and options but nothing did help. I hope anyone could help me to get solve this error.

the errors displayed are the syntax errors of some java files related to the plugin